# PHP mysql json_set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, set

I am stuck with the following: I have a mysql database (5.7). I want to update a json-data-entry.

This is how my data in the database looks like:

```
{
    "version": {
        "0": {
            "value": "1.9.6.81"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to update this field with SQL directly from the command line there is no issue:

```
update item set elements = JSON_SET(elements, '$."version"."0"."value"', "1.9.8.40") where name like 'Client XZY';
```

but when I try it with PHP, I have some issues with the mixed quotes and double quotes.

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password');    
$updateSql = "update item set elements = JSON_SET(elements, '$."version'.'0'.'value"', '1.9.8.20') where name like 'Client XYZ';';

if($connection->query($updateSql) === TRUE){
        echo 'good :) ';
}
else{
        echo 'bad :( ';
}
```

Comment: Simply put a backslash before any quote that you also use as the literal delimiter. I.e., if your PHP string literal starts with `"`, you need to write every `"` within that string as `\"`.

Comment: provide your input element like version is variable ?

Comment: tried with this update string, no success
`$updateSql = "update item set elements = JSON_SET(elements, '$.\"version'.\"0\".\"value\"', '1.9.8.20') where name like 'Client XYZ';";`

Answer (score 0):

got it working

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxx');
mysqli_select_db($connection,"MYSQL5");

$updateSql = "UPDATE item SET elements = JSON_SET(elements, '$.\"version\".\"0\".\"value\"', '1.9.8.40') WHERE name LIKE 'lient XYZ';";

if($connection->query($updateSql) === TRUE){
        echo 'good :)';
}
else{
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $connection->error);
}
```